# Put CDATA It is a good practice or not necessarily - Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, best-practice

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  //<![CDATA[
    Some code...
  //]]>
</script>
```

We agree that magento use the **CDATA** in `javascript` pieces codes, but I would like to know which is really the utility of this. There are some who say that we should put it in the **XHTML** and **XML**. So for **exemple** in some phtml, if i need to add a javascript function to validate some field or add a class etc ... i should add the **CDATA** between the code or not necessarily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found also this answer:

It to ensure that **XHTML** validation works correctly when you have JavaScript embedded in your page, rather than externally referenced.

**XHTML** requires that your page strictly conform to **XML** markup requirements. Since JavaScript may contain characters with special meaning, you must wrap it in **CDATA** to ensure that validation does not flag it as malformed.

> With HTML pages on the web you can just include the required
>   JavaScript between and tags. When you validate the HTML on your web
>   page the JavaScript content is considered to be CDATA (character data)
>   that is therefore ignored by the validator. The same is not true if
>   you follow the more recent XHTML standards in setting up your web
>   page. With XHTML the code between the script tags is considered to be
>   PCDATA (parsed character data) which is therefore processed by the
>   validator.
>
> Because of this, you can't just include JavaScript between the script tags on your page without 'breaking' your web page (at least as
>   far as the validator is concerned).